# use Curl in foreach

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I am working on project need to get last video from many channels in `Youtube` and store it in mysql now I work in file it is work by cron job every on hours to check last video , the problem now I have more than 30 channels and I use curl to get last video in every channel ,you can see the code

```
foreach ($channels as $channel){


     $channel_id =  $channel['channel_id'];

     $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
         CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=$channel_id&maxResults=50&order=date&key=$key" ,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
   ));
   $json = curl_exec($curl);
   $data_json = json_decode($json , TRUE);
   $item = $data_json['items'][0];
  // complete code here to check last video  
}
```

now my qustion is:

1- is it good idea or there are better?

2 - are there any problem to use many request Curl in youtube api?
Thanks

Comment: please clarify more, how often do you want to call this code? and how are the files are going to be stored?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API v2 supported [batch operations](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_batch_processing); API v3 no longer does.  You could do try to run multiple requests in parallel using [`curl_multi_init()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php).

If you only care about one item per request, don't request `maxResults=50`.

Do all of the videos have something else in common?  For example, are the all uploaded by the authenticated user?  If so, try searching for videos uploaded by that user (`forMine=true`), `publishedAfter` the time of the previous cron job.  Then triage the results according to each video's `channelId`.

Comment: good point maxResults=1 but i think curl_multi_init() is not good here